# .NET6 Web-API returning result needs too much time

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

It needs just a second to retreive all the data and convert it to `IEnumerable<MYORDERS>` with micro-ORM dapper. But within the `return OK(result)`-statement it takes several minutes to get the result. I think it is because JSON-mapping.

Why does it take so long and what is a possible good solution?

```
public object GetOrders()
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(StaticValues.ConnString))
    {
        IEnumerable<MYORDERS> result =
            //Micro-ORM dapper used
            conn.Query<MYORDERS>("SELECT * FROM MY_ORDER_TABLE");

        //This line takes several minutes
        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

My POCO `MYORDERS` got like 70 properties. The result got 900 rows/POCOs. I thought an API should also easily transfer this amount of data.

Edit:
Ok, I see that JSON-mapping isn't my problem. It just needs minutes to create the output:

```
//no serializing problem
var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(await result);

//returning json needs some minutes
return json;
```

The output-json-string got 1,2 millions of characters. Maybe it is because the swagger-ui.. Can't belive 1 million characters will take this amount of time...

I will update this question again when I finally deployed it on our IIS. This will take a few days.

Comment: It depends on your model mapping complexity. If there is nested models that will be mapped with 3 or more layer, some mapping libraries takes minutes. Which one do you prefer ?

Comment: There is no further nesting. It is just an IENUMERABLE with 900 rows with a simple POCO

Comment: I use swagger for testing. I think it should easily transfer 900 rows :/ Maybe the problem is fixed on deployment. I will test it in few days but I don't think this will fix it.

Comment: Ah, jeah, my POCO got like 70 properties. Maybe this forces the problem..

Comment: Try using Postman or directly querying the API.  This should eliminate any UI lag caused by swagger.

Comment: FYI - Because `result` is `IEnumerable` it won't fetch the data until it is enumerated. So, `return Ok(result);` is actually retreiving the data from the database ___and___ serializing the data to JSON.

Comment: Thank you  Kami & @phuzi ! Yea, the lag was because of swagger... An usual request don't need this amount of time... Damn, this took me some time -,-

Comment: Btw, i don't believe 70 props object is still called simple POCO.

Comment:  Yeah, didn't realised it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @phuzi said as a comment swagger-ui forced the lag... An usual request with postman just takes some milliseconds....

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1):

I would try this

```
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<MYORDERS>> GetOrders()
{
    ... your code
}
```

Comment: Didn't help, but thank you very much. I did a little bit more research. It is just because it is too much data :/ I will update my question!

Comment: @Basssprosse You are welcome! In any case it is always better to use a typed return than an object